# Reacttabulator when initial data is null throws error

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

In ReactTabulator ,when initial data is null then placeholder in table is not shown instead it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: Post the code also

Comment: I got the solution for this. Just had to keep it empty instead of null ..